2 videos rendering at the same time when Stacked
I am trying to create 2 Stacked VideoPlayer widget on top of each other, with a slider beneath them to fade between the 2 video tracks. It uses the Opacity Widget with an opacity value regulated by the slider. Easy enough. Problem is when playing the videos, they should both be started and playing at the same time. As soon as I slide it over one way or the other, one of the videos stops playing. I guess this has to do with the way flutter does rendering of "active and viewable" widgets, so it pauses the video playback of "background" streams.
Can one of you recommend me a way to achieve this?
Here is my (stripped down) code for completeness. It has a GestureDetector around it to do resetAndPlayVideos onTap:
void _resetAndPlayVideos() {
  // Reset all videos to the beginning (0.0) and play them
  final position = Duration.
zero
;
  _controller1.seekTo(position).then((_) {
    _controller1.play(); // Start playing after seeking
  });
  _controller2.seekTo(position).then((_) {
    _controller2.play(); // Start playing after seeking
  });
  _controller3.seekTo(position).then((_) {
    _controller3.play(); // Start playing after seeking
  });
}




Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          // Video 1 at the bottom
          if (_controller1.value.isInitialized)
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: _getOpacityForVideo1(),
                child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _controller1!.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: VideoPlayer(_controller1)),
              ),
            ),
          // Video 2 on top
          if (_controller2.value.isInitialized)
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: _getOpacityForVideo2(),
                child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _controller2!.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: VideoPlayer(_controller2)),
              ),
            ),        ],
      ),
    ),
    // Slider at the bottom to transition between videos
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Slider(
        value: _fadeValue,
        min: 0.0,
        max: 1.0,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _fadeValue = value; // Adjust the opacity for fade effect
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
)


If you perhaps want them to fade, you could use an animated switcher Hoegje. It takes the child widget, like the first player, and fades it with the new widget, like the second playback player. So you could have a variable that checks which of the controllers are active and take it as the main widget. If you're using GET as well, you could use an obs variable to determine when to display the relevant widget whilst keeping the played "state" of each of the controllers for the playback players. Official Video: https://youtu.be/2W7POjFb88g?si=V3UQzPIqImeFifC-

You can then have a list or a similar structure to choose the correct controller for the specific playback.

Actually, I would like them to both play simultaneously on top of each other, and have the Slider control just the opacity. Now whenever I set the slider to a little left of center, and tap the video, the "left" video plays, and the right one pauses. Then I slide over the slider a bit to the right of center, the left video keeps on playing (with setLooping true) and then when I tap the video again only the rightmost video starts playing and the left one is paused. I want them both to keep playing.

You can use an active state controller, assigning a current controller based on the scroll position:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  currentActiveController = Controller();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Durations.medium1,
          child: Column(children: VideoPlayer(_currentActiveController)),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

Or potentially using the scroll position to provide a different video player:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  final currentActiveController = Controller();
  double scrollPos = 0.0 ; 
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Durations.medium1,
          child: Column(children: scrollPos > controller1.position : VideoPlayer(controller1) ? const SizedBox.shrink() ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

But without knowing the internals of VideoPlayer, I won't be able to assist further. Hope this helps :)

VideoPlayer is from flutter package video_player: ^2.9.1. I'll have a look at your suggestions.

Actually, I would like them to both play simultaneously on top of each other, and have the Slider control just the opacity. Now whenever I set the slider to a little left of center, and tap the video, the "left" video plays, and the right one pauses. Then I slide over the slider a bit to the right of center, the left video keeps on playing (with setLooping true) and then when I tap the video again only the rightmost video starts playing and the left one is paused. I want them both to keep playing. I will have to look for another video player option, I think.
